# MVC 6 Entity Framework 7 UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync error

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add an ApplicationUser id to a table and need to validate the user first.

In prior mvc's you could validate with **Membership.ValidateUser**, but this doesn't seem to be an option with MVC 6, so I'm trying the **UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync**.

**Failing Code**

```
bool bCorrectPassword = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.New_Player_Detail.TSIC_Password);
if (bCorrectPassword)
{
    Family_Members record = new Family_Members()
    {
        Family_UserId = model.Family_Details.Family_UserId,
        Family_Member_UserId = user.Id,
        modified = DateTime.Now,
        lebUserID = model.Family_Details.Family_UserId
    };

    db.Family_Members.Add(record);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("EditFamilyAccount", new { StatusMessage = String.Format("Player: {0} has been added to your family account.", model.New_Player_Detail.TSIC_Username) });
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("EditFamilyAccount", new { StatusMessage = "Credentials for new player were not valid." });
}
```

UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync returns correct results (true if true, false if any non-matching combination of username/password), however:

The await db.SaveChangesAsync() will fail with:

***A database operation failed while processing the request.
DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.***

Now simply comment out the UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync and it works fine.  Somehow UserManger.CheckPasswordAsync is holding the account record... can't be sure, very difficult to debug.

Try Catch doesn't add anything beyond the DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

**Successful Code**

```
//bool bCorrectPassword = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.New_Player_Detail.TSIC_Password);
//if (bCorrectPassword)
//{
    Family_Members record = new Family_Members()
    {
        Family_UserId = model.Family_Details.Family_UserId,
        Family_Member_UserId = user.Id,
        modified = DateTime.Now,
        lebUserID = model.Family_Details.Family_UserId
    };

    db.Family_Members.Add(record);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("EditFamilyAccount", new { StatusMessage = String.Format("Player: {0} has been added to your family account.", model.New_Player_Detail.TSIC_Username) });
//}
//else
//{
//    return RedirectToAction("EditFamilyAccount", new { StatusMessage = "Credentials for new player were not valid." });
//}
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?  I've tried replacing the UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync call with SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync and I get the exact same error.

Addendum:  I've run sql trace across the CheckPasswordAsync step and EF indeed issues a UserUpdate (including ConcurrencyStamp):

**SQL Trace of CheckPasswordAsync (Parameter values omitted)**

```
UPDATE [AspNetUsers] 
SET [AccessFailedCount] = @p0, [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p1, [Email] = @p3, [EmailConfirmed] = @p4, [FirstName] = @p5, [LastName] = @p7, [LockoutEnabled] = @p8, [LockoutEnd] = @p9, [LockoutEndDateUtc] = @p10, [NormalizedEmail] = @p11, [NormalizedUserName] = @p12, [PasswordHash] = @p13, [PhoneNumber] = @p14, [PhoneNumberConfirmed] = @p15, [SecurityStamp] = @p16, [TwoFactorEnabled] = @p17, [UserName] = @p18, [cellphone] = @p19, [cellphoneProvider] = @p20, [city] = @p21, [country] = @p22, [dob] = @p23, [fax] = @p24, [gender] = @p25, [imageFile] = @p26, [imageFileMimeType] = @p27, [phone] = @p28, [postalCode] = @p29, [state] = @p30, [streetAddress] = @p31, [workphone] = @p32
WHERE [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p2 AND [Id] = @p6;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: You should post this at the ofical github issue list. Probly a bug that must be solved!